# Unable to see a plot produced by python igraph in OS X 10.10.2

Tags: python, visualization, igraph, anaconda

I am trying to visualize a simple graph created with the igraph library. I already installed cairo and their respective bindings for Anaconda (2.7.8) (I can see cairo when I type help('modules')) following these posts [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/149) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651439/add-cairo-package-in-the-anaconda-python-distribution). However, when I run my code in sublime text 2, I cannot see the image and instead I get `sh: open: command not found`. Am I missing something? This is my code

```
import igraph


g = igraph.Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
igraph.summary(g)

print g.degree()
print g.edge_betweenness()


# Drawing a graph
layout = g.layout("kk")
igraph.plot(g, layout = layout)
```

Comment: Try to use: from igraph import * and then use plot(g, layout = layout) directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 opens a shell in the background to run your Python code. This shell seems to look for executables in `/bin` (and maybe `/sbin`) only. The `open` command (which igraph needs to open Preview.app to show the plot) resides in `/usr/bin`, and probably that's why the plot does not work from Sublime Text.

Try creating a file named `.igraphrc` in your home directory with the following contents:

```
[apps]
image_viewer = /usr/bin/open
```

This file tells igraph to use `/usr/bin/open` to show the plot and not just `open`. Let me know if it fixed plotting for you - if so, I'll commit a patch for the next version.

Comment: it does not work. I get the same `sh: open: command not found` Any other suggestion?

Comment: Okay, so I installed Sublime Text 2 and tried to show a plot using igraph's `plot` function. It worked perfectly fine, so I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with your environment. Does the `open` command work from the command line? E.g., try `open /Applications/iTunes.app` from the Terminal.

Comment: It works when I typed `open /Applications/iTunes.app` but when I tried to build the igraph code (visualize) it says `ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: /Users/username/.igraphrc, line: 1
'{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1344\\cocoasubrtf720\n'`

Comment: You seem to have edited `.igraphrc` in TextEdit.app and then saved it in RTF format. Use an editor which saves in plain text format.

Answer (score 0):

The `open` command is missing. This command is used by igraph to open the produced plot (try `open some_image.png` in a terminal, you should get the same error). I'm not sure how to get the open command on a mac, but if that's not included by default, it looks like a bug in igraph, that it is trying to use it.

You could try the ipython notebook (`conda install ipython-notebook; ipython notebook` and then add your code in the opened browser), which will show the plots inline or try to save and open the plot yourself in `finder`.

Comment: The `open` command is part of OS X so it shouldn't be missing from the OP's machine. However, it is in `/usr/bin` and it may be the case that the shell launched by Sublime Text (in which it runs the Python code) does not include `/usr/bin` in the path.