# symbol lookup error after updating conda 'undefined symbol: cairo_ft_font_options_substitute'

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, conda

Last week I updated conda to version 3.11.0, after that I found either `%pylab` or `plt.plot` would encounter the symbol lookup error.

```
min@home:~$ ipython
In [1]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
/home/min/anaconda/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_ft_font_options_substitute

min@home:~$ ipython
In [1]: %pylab
/home/min/anaconda/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_ft_font_options_substitute
```

I've reinstalled Anaconda and everything turned to fine, but once I `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda`, the error showed up again.

Comment: Got a similar error, with a different module/function name though: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index. Did not managed to get it to work inside of anaconda unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the difference between "conda update conda" and "conda update cairo", I tried the second but didn't fix it in my fedora 20 i686, even though some packages were updated. [1]

So, I kept looking and I found [2], just the tittle made me think in "conda install cairo", and now most of my older scripts which uses matplotlib work fine.

sources:

[1]https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/R0RdG3HQONg/r_LM-Al6b1YJ

[2][add cairo package in the anaconda python distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651439/add-cairo-package-in-the-anaconda-python-distribution)